# How to replace '?' delimiting with white space delimiting in string

Tags: regex, perl, www-mechanize

I am working with a set of links from `WWW::Mechanize` and would like to simply print a list of the link names and url's that were retrieved from a page. Oddly, the names, pulled up with `$link->name()`, are coming back with `'?'` characters where spaces would be. I have tried to fix this using the following methods:

1)

```
{
my $name = $link->text();
$name =~ s/\?/" "/g;
}
```

2) As suggested in other posts on replacing the '?' character:

```
{
my $name = $link->text();
my $pat = quotemeta '?';
$name =~ s/$pat/" "/g;
}
```

Both methods do nothing to the $name string! What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($name)); }`

Comment: I'm guessing that the `?`s are probably due to encoding issues, check that both your input/output and terminal viewer are all set to utf8.

Comment: @user3396385 this is a long shot but when you `print $name`, are you using the variable `$name` that is in your block or is it a different `$name` variable outside of your block?

Comment: Just checked this and I think you're right. There is some odd character where the question marks show up in the output strings. I'll try your suggestion and see if it works!

Comment: @user3396385 `use utf8` fixes it :) ?

Comment: I think it should, however I'm having problems figuring out how to make sure the content returned by $mech->get uses utf8 encoding. Clearly just loading the module isn't enough. I just have not found where to specify that within the WWW::Mechanize object. There is no charset in the meta info on the pages I'm retrieving so should be using whatever default is built into WWW::Mechanize, I think.

Comment: Okay, I'm stymied by how to do this... I'm sure it's simple but I'm not finding what I need. Tried adding '$mech->add_header('Accept-Charset' => 'utf8');' and using '$mech->decoded_content()' and no luck. If it helps, I'm on a 32 bit Mac and I'm retrieving recs from a Windows server (all files I'm parsing are .asp files).

Comment: The reason a `?` is being shown is an encoding issue, not because you actually have a `?`. So the first things to do is find out what you actually have. So again I ask, what's the output of `use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($name)); }`.

Comment: @Jord, `use utf8;` merely tells Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8. It won't matter here.

Comment: The second thing to do is determine the encoding your terminal expects. What OS do you use?

Comment: Okay, did that and I get '\240' for the ? chars. Tried again using 'quotemeta "\240";' and that fixes the problem! Still confused as to why I'm getting this to begin with. Can this be fixed by specifying the charset in WWW::Mechanize, like I was trying to do?

Comment: 240 octal is A0 hex, which is the NBSP, not a question. That's why removing `?` didn't help. `s/\xA0/ /g` would help, but better yet, let's encode the string correctly for your terminal instead. What OS do you use? (And include `@ikegami` in your reply so I get notified!)

Comment: @ikegami  I am using Mac OS 10.6.8, 32 bit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Then it's probably UTF-8. `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per ikegami, in comment thread:

The reason a ? is being shown is an encoding issue, not because you actually have a ?. So the first things to do is find out what you actually have. So again I ask, what's the output of use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($name)); }.

I get '\240' for the ? chars. Tried again using 'quotemeta "\240";' and that fixes the problem!

240 octal is A0 hex, which is the NBSP, not a question. That's why removing ? didn't help. s/\xA0/ /g would help, but better yet, let's encode the string correctly for your terminal instead.

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```